# Randomly distributed pursuers on a lattice

Tags: graph-theory

Take a lattice of size $n^2$ where $n$ is the length of each side. Now on these $n$ points randomly distribute five cops and one murderer. What is the expected distance from the nearest cop to the murderer (in terms of lattice points that is)?

Comment: I expect we can solve the one-dimensional lattice problem then transform the answer (e.g. approximately double it), since components are chosen independently and in lattices those componentwise distances are additive. But I don't know how this affects the choice of "closest" cop.

Comment: [Aslo posted at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279856/expected-distance-on-n-times-n-lattice).